# Is it possible to make a UILabel editable in swift?

Tags: swift, uilabel, uitextview

I would like my users to be able to edit a `UIlabel` in my app, similar to how the `UITextView`, when clicked, brings up a keyboard to edit the text. I want to use a `UILabel` instead of a `UITextView` because I need to be able to hide this view and it does not seem possible to hide a `UITextView`. I have also tried using a `UITextField` but this does not work either because I need the content to wrap.

Comment: well you can add a tap gesture recognizer to it and present a UIAlertController with a UITextField. Dont forget to enable [user interaction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622577-isuserinteractionenabled)

Comment: There's several ways. But the deeper question is **why**? UITextViews exist for this reason, and UILabels are different for *just* that - specific reasons. as such, your question is quite vague. I'm guessing you already know how straightforward it is to bring up (and dismiss) the keyboard for text entry. And probably you could even move such text entry into a label where it can be... formatted? Not directly edited? And THAT is what's vague about your question.

Comment: @dfd I have attempted to use```UITextView``` to solve my issue, however I need to be able to hide the view, which the textview is unable to do. I also want a containing view to adjust to the size of the label which again the text view will not do.

Comment: @leodabus I am working on using a tap gesture recognizer and will probably have to use some sort of animator to get this to work. I would like to avoid using an alert view to make the app a bit more seamless

Comment: I'd like to remove my downvote, but cannot without an edit on your part. A suggestion for that edit? Nothing in your question details anything about *hiding* this view. Nor using a container view. (I'm not saying that can be accomplished without what you are trying - but I may be saying where your question indicates what's vague and therefore not reproducible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make a UILabel editable in swift?

Not directly; you'd have to replace it with an object that supports editing. The `UILabel` docs say, right at the top:

> *A view that displays one or more lines of informational text.*

In other words, `UILabel` is for **display** of text; there's nothing in there that supports editing. So, if you want to let the user edit the content of a label, you have to temporarily replace the label with an editable object such as `UITextView` or `UITextField` or something of your own creation.

**TL/DR:** If you're using a label for text that needs to be editable, you're probably using the wrong tool for the job.

> I want to use a UILabel instead of a UITextView because I need to be able to hide this view and it does not seem possible to hide a UITextView.

I'm not sure why you'd say that; `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIView`, and therefore it has a `hidden` property just like every other view. There's also an `alpha` property that doesn't so much hide the view as make it transparent, but which may still be useful in some cases. And one more option, if the previous two don't work for some reason, is to "hide" the view by removing it from the view graph. But just setting the `hidden` property should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can input the text from textField then showing result in label